# Do ICS files contain any info about online meetings?

Tags: icalendar

In my application I need to understand if the ICS file represents an online meeting (Teams, Meet, Zoom...) or not.

I read the [RFC5545 standard docs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), but I couldn't find any specific standard attribute. I also analyzed the content of some online events created inside Google Calendar or Microsoft Teams and found out that Google puts a custom string

```
X-GOOGLE-CONFERENCE:your-meeting-link
```

while Microsoft specifies this info in the LOCATION attribute like "Teams meeting".

Is there anything standard across multiple providers? Is there any discussion about this to be done in the future?